# Thread guarantee in spring @Scheduled tasks

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, threadpoolexecutor, spring-scheduled

I have a class with two @Scheduled methods as follows.

```
public class JobExecutor {
    private static final DelayQueue<Job> JOB_QUEUE = new DelayQueue<>();

    @Scheduled
    public void run() {
        Job job = JOB_QUEUE.take();
    }

    @Scheduled 
    public void fillQueue {
       JOB_QUEUE.add(.....);
    }
}
```

I am using a thread pool with 20 threads. Now I am using a `DelayQueue` which is a blocking queue in the `run` method. Is there a possibility that all the 20 threads gets stuck reading the queue(when it is empty)  and the `fillQueue` method never gets executed?

Answer (score 0):

No, because DelayQueue returns null if there are no elements for poll

Comment: Actually I am doing a take(). Not poll().

Answer (score 0):

If have had a look into the code. If you configure the scheduler pool by xml

```
<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="10"/>
```

then the pool-size will become the corePoolSize of the builded `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`

```
ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.createExecutor line 146:
new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(poolSize, threadFactory, rejectedExecutionHandler);
```

and the `maximumPoolSize` will be `Integer.MAX_VALUE` !

Therefor the answer is: NO, it is just a core pool size and more threads will been created if they are requested. So your code will not block.